# Service isn't firing off post request in Angular 4.x

Tags: angular, http, post, angular-services

I have the following function `uploadCSV` within a service that should post to an endpoint for upload a csv - I can see in the console log that the csvfile is there however when checking the network tab there isn't any POST request shown - any ideas why?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from "../../../services/api.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class BulkuploadService {

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private userService: UserService
) { }

uploadCSV(csvFile: any): any {
    console.log(csvFile);
    let formData:FormData = new FormData;
    formData.append('file', csvFile, csvFile.name);
    console.log(formData);

    let url = this.apiService.getApiUrl('bulk-upload/upload');
    console.log(url);

    return this.http.post(url, formData);
}

}
```

// component

```
import { Component, 
OnInit, 
Inject,
Input, 
Output, 
EventEmitter, 
ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { BulkuploadService } from './bulkupload.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-bulkupload',
templateUrl: './bulkupload.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./bulkupload.component.scss'],
providers: [
    BulkuploadService
]
})
export class BulkuploadComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() closeEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
private postObjects = [];

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,
    private ref: ElementRef,
    public bulkService: BulkuploadService    
) { }

uploadCSV(event: any): void {
    this.bulkService.uploadCSV(event.target.files[0]);
}

}
```

Comment: not subscribing to the post call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables are lazy , you need to subscribe to it in order for it to execute.

```
 uploadCSV(event: any): void {
    this.bulkService.uploadCSV(event.target.files[0]).subscribe(data => {
      //handle next steps after execution
    },err=>{
      //handle error
    },()=>{
      //completed
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe the http post call like in [this](https://angular.io/guide/http) example:

```
showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    .subscribe((data: Config) => this.config = {
        heroesUrl: data['heroesUrl'],
        textfile:  data['textfile']
    });
}
```